# Browser Option on View Results Tree JMeter

Tags: jmeter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao0Fa.png)

I have JMeter 5.1.1 . There is 'View Result Tree' on Listeners. And also there are some Types that types of show content. I explain in that way cause of somebody closes my questions. Whatever...
And I can see browser option on view results tree. But now, I set up Jmeter 5.1.1 to another pc. Same Operating System and same version of JMeter(downloaded from same link same version). But there is no browser option(Listeners>View Result Tree>Types> There is no BROWSER). I dont remember adding any plugin or something else for it(As you can understand the previous sentences I have Browser Option). Is it come by default? Or not? Now Here is my question: How can I add Browser Option? 
Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

Most probably "another pc" doesn't have [JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/overview/jfxpub-overview.htm) installed presumably due to running [OpenJDK](https://openjdk.java.net/)

You can check which exactly Java you have on both pc's by running `java --version` command, if you see `OpenJDK` there - you don't have JavaFX and hence don't have the "Browser" option.

The solution would be manually installing [OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) and setting `PATH_TO_FX` environment variable pointing to the OpenJFX installation folder. Once done you will have the "Browser" option back in the View Results Tree listener.

Another option is just using [Oracle JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html)

In any case as per [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/) article you should be always using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity

Comment: It was because of jdk version. JMeter takes version 8 of jdk. I edit variables to version 8 and it solved.